# Python mpl_toolkits.mplot3d "Unable to resolve 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module"

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, matplotlib, intellisense

I am new to Python. I am trying to calling mpl_toolkits.mplot3d in VS2017 Python, but it keeps informing me "Unable to resolve 'mpl_toolkits.mplot3d'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module". How am I gonna fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGGYE.png)